# Aligning inside li element text and picture PHP

Tags: php, mysql, list, drop-down-menu, alignment

**Hello,**

I have a problem with aligning text and picture inside li element. The **li** consist of one word and one picture (for example English [picture]). I need that picture would go to the right side and text would stay as it is (now it is goes to the left side). The code looks like:

```
    for($i=0; $i < $rowCount; $i++){        
?>
<li><a href="?lang=<?php echo $l[$i]?>"><?php echo $i?><img src="/flags/flag_of_lithuania.gif" width="20" height="10"> </a></li>
<?php
}
```

Now it prints language and picture, however everything aligned to the left side. **Looking for any help :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    for($i=0; $i < $rowCount; $i++){        
?>
<li><a href="?lang=<?php echo $l[$i]?>"><?php echo $i?><img style="float:right" src="/flags/flag_of_lithuania.gif" width="20" height="10"> </a></li>
<?php
}
```

Comment: The problem is when staring blind on a problem is that your brain forgets the simple way out because it won't think outside the box.